# Горизонтальная прокрутка карт

Tags: css, прокрутка

Пытаюсь оформить в группу новость, нужна горизонтальная прокрутка картинок, в блоге прокрутка ставится и смотрится как надо, но на другом сайте, там, где надо оформить новость, когда вставляю этот же код, то никакой прокрутки нет. Вот код:

```css
.scrolling {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50em;
  height: 10em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  word-wrap: normal; 
}

.scrolling img {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">    
  <br />
  <div class="scrolling">
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
    <img alt="" src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1612/51/2bfe9c822041.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи, потому что совсем не разбираюсь в этих кодах... но оформить очень хочется красиво. Благодарю.

Comment: К сожалению, на глаз определить проблему затруднительно, поскольку непонятно какие другие стили с сайта, куда вы вставляете ваш код, переопределяют стили, представленные в примере. Предоставьте хотя бы скриншот того, как это выглядит после вставки.

Comment: вторая картинка-это то, как выглядит всё после вставки, т.е все картинки в ряд и без прокрутки

Comment: если я правильно интерпретирую скриншот, то это предпросмотр новости в текстовом редакторе админки сайта. опять же, можно строить разные предположения, но будет замечательно попробовать эту новость запостить и посмотреть её вживую — так можно увидеть какие еще стили влияют на отображение, меняет ли редактор ваш код и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно там отсутствует библиотека JQuery! или проверьте - horizontal overflow возможно там - hidden

Comment: И как же отсутствие jquery должно влиять на то, что сделано вообще без скриптов?

Comment: с данной проблемой встречался тоже! есть в Wordpress-e темы которые выдают такой код и вроде можно скопировать на другой сайт и всё заработает но Нет! Если заметить то: Ответ предположительный так как автор не уточняет деталей!!!

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, что уточнить надо?

Comment: на каких сайтах работаете ? 
ссылки где нормально работает и где не работает можете дать ?
пробовали сохранить и просмотреть результат ?

Comment: горизонтальная прокрутка ставится правильно на Blogger ,оттуда я и скопировала код, когда поставила прокрутку с картинками, а вот на сайт  http://www.playcast.ru/  , когда в новость вставляла этот код, то прокрутки нет.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять overflow-x: auto; или overflow-x: visible

Comment: пробовала заменить, но ничего не даёт, видимо...такой сайт,там встаёт только вертикальная прокрутка

Comment: как последний вариант, overflow-x: auto!important; overflow-x: scroll!important;  но возможно есть запрет с сайта на скрол

Comment: вы наверное контент менеджер, я не знаю как вы на этот сайт попали )) но вам на будущее пригодится знания html css рекомендую [tutorial] (https://www.youtube.com/user/ArtSorax)

Comment: огромное спасибо за советы и рекомендации